# Добавление в jstree node

Tags: javascript, jquery

Столкнулся с проблемой, не могу добавить новый элемент дерева jstree. Подскажите знатоки как правильно добавлять новые parent node используя обработчик кнопки.
Вот пример:

```
$("#CreateButton").button().click(function (){

    var ref =  $("treeview").jstree("create_node", null, null, "last", function (node) {
       alert(ref);
      this.edit(node);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенном коде минимум две ошибки: 
в `$("treeview")` забыли `#` или `.`,
переменной `ref` еще не присвоено значение в момент вызова `alert(ref)`.

Рабочий пример (заменил `alert` на `console.log`)

```js
$("#treeview").jstree({
  "core": {
    "animation": 0,
    "check_callback": true,
    "themes": {
      "stripes": true
    }
  }
});

$("#CreateButton").button().click(function() {

  var ref = $("#treeview").jstree("create_node", null, 'New node', "last", function(node) {
    console.log(node.text);
    this.edit(node);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.1/jstree.min.js"></script>

<button id="CreateButton">New</button>
<div id="treeview"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!